# Cannot fire "CheckAll" Method - jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have all of my options selected in my [Multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) widget on startup.

In the documentation, it says:

> After an instance has been initialized, interact with it by calling any of these methods:
>
> // example:
> $("#multiselect").multiselect("method_name");
>
> checkAll ------   Check all checkboxes.

So I did this:

```
$("#music").multiselect("checkAll");
```

And this is the error I got:

> Error: cannot call methods on multiselect prior to initialization;
> attempted to call method 'checkAll' [Break On This Error]
>
> throw new Error( msg );

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error message says it all really. You need to initialise the plugin on the element before trying to call a plugin method.

Something like this:

```
$("#music").multiselect({
    // initialisation options...
});
$("#music").multiselect("checkAll"); // call the method
```

Comment: Ahh, I thought this option was built into the plugin.

Comment: It is - but you still need to create an instance of the plugin first in order to access the methods.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize it first and then call the method

```
var $musicSelect = $('#music');

$musicSelect.multiselect();   // Initialize

$musicSelect.multiselect("checkAll");  // CheckAll
```